# Raspberry Pi + SIM808 + I2C

Tags: pi-3, i2c

I am trying to communicate my raspberry pi 3 model b with a GPS / GPRS SIM 808 module (808 EVB-V3.2 SIM). I want to use for this I2C ports, which are already enabled on my raspberry. However, raspberry does not detect the SIM808 when I connect the SDA, SCL and GND pins when I run the **sudo i2cdetect-y 1** command (it does not display anything).

The connection I made is as follows:

Raspberry ____ SIM808

SDA (pin 3) ----> SDA (pin 38)

SCL (pin 5) ----> SCL (pin 39)

GND ----> GND

So, should I enable these pins on the SIM808 before connecting it to my raspberry? I have not found information about it, nor AT commands to configure the I2C pins, then I do not know why my raspberry does not recognize it.

Or should I connect another additional pin to establish the connection?

Any information about it will be very helpful.

Thank you

Raspberry model: http://pi4j.com/pins/model-3b-rev1.html

SIM 808 model: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheet ... _V1.00.pdf

Comment: Why do you think the device is controllable over I2C?

Comment: To be fair, IF it's got SDA and SCL, it's a not-illogical assumption... Although I don't think that's how you use it. Interestingly, none of those pins is "power" so that's something to look at. Also, see if there's TX and RX available - that's more likely to give you comms ability. TX->RX on Pi, RX->TX on Pi.